# Reformat Timespan in C#

Tags: c#, timespan

I have several strings that look like such:

where S represents seconds and M represents minutes

```
"MM Minutes and XX Seconds"
"MM Minutes"
"SS Seconds"
":SS"
```

How would I convert that to one of the following:
String format "MM:SS"
TimeSpan format

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You could use [TempusReader](http://github.com/ChrisMissal/TempusReader). It's an open source project that I started to solve this exact problem *(and to teach myself how to use [Parsley](http://github.com/plioi/Parsley))*.

Take a look at the examples on the GitHub page and see if it suits your needs. It will work for words like `and` in your first example. Like so:

```
TimeSpan x = new Time("2 days, 7 hours, 12 mins and 52 seconds") // 2.07:12:52
```

Also, a `TempusReader.Time` object can be implicitly cast to a `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this as well if you want to test with DateTime.Now for example

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(currentTime);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds));
```